# Powershell - extract values from lines with a "template"

Tags: regex, string, powershell, parsing

I have a file which contains lines matching the following template:

```
this folder <FolderName> permission needs to be removed for user NT User:<SID>
this folder <FolderName1> permission needs to be removed for user NT User:<SID2>
```

Where `<FolderName>` and `<SID>` are the values I'm trying to pull out to work with.

`<FolderName>` can contain any number of UTF8 characters.

How do I parse out the value from each line?  I'm stuck - pretty sure regex is the way forward but I'm at a loss.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - my problem was that I was completely stuck.  I know how to get things that match, but not things near things that match.  It was a situation of "I can't think of any way to do this" :(

Comment: That's _why_ I (and others) will ask what you've tried and how it's failed - it shows us something about your thought process, and gives us a clue how to redirect you if needed - the idea is not just to give you quick-and-dirty code that works (and @ShamusBerube lies when he says "quick and dirty"; that's actually a pretty workable solution), but to "teach" you how to approach the problem so that you can generalize solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
Get-Content "Filename.txt" | Foreach-Object {
    $values = $_.Replace('this folder','').Replace(''permission needs to be removed for user NT User','').Split(':')
    $folder = $values[0]
    $sid = $values[1]
}
```